# How to make global arrays and dwords in x86 assembly?

Tags: arrays, assembly, x86, global-variables, dword

How exactly do you make multiple global arrays of bytes and multiple dwords in x86? Also, how do you initialize them all to 0? Would this be done in _start: or in section .data? The assembler to be used is NASM.

Comment: Variable scope and arrays are concepts from higher level languages. Unless you start changing the segment registers everything is global, and an array is just a contiguous block of memory addressed by pointers and offsets.

Comment: Alright. How would you allocate memory for two arrays?

Answer (score 1):

Nasm syntax - 100 bytes / dwords:

```
section .bss
    byte_array resb 100
    dword_array resd 100

; or...
section .data
    byte_array_2 times 100 db 0
    dword_array_2 times 100 dd 0

global _start  ; ask Nasm to tell linker about this
section .text
    _start:
    ; do something intelligent...
```

`section .bss` is nominally "uninitialized", but is in fact initialized to zero on any reasonable platform. Fasm uses `rb` and `rd` instead of `resb` and `resd`. You didn't say "what assembler".

Comment: Oops i didnt. NASM is what I am looking for.